# AdMob Native Advanced Ad unit ID

Tags: ios, swift, admob

How do I get AdMob Native Advanced Ad unit ID.

I have implemented Native Advanced Ad with Native Express Ad unit ID but It shows no ad to show as an error.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-advanced) it might be help you.

Comment: on this link we only get how to implement native advanced ad and an Ad unit ID for testing purpose.

Comment: Sign in to your AdMob account at https://apps.admob.com.
If not create one, but google suggest to prefer fireBase.

Comment: You can create Ad unit ID for native that is only used for native express small,medium, large ad size. If we use native Ad unit ID for native advanced then it shows error no ad to show.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have implemented native ads unit in your app, so I think you want to know your ad unit ID.

To know your ad unit ID, go to the monetization option from [admob](https://apps.admob.com) (Hope you have already an account and created ads unit), then from right sidebar, select your apps from all apps option menu, and there you will see your AD unit Id.